# Why is lpop increasing Redis CPU usage?

Tags: go, redis

I have an application which keeps looping while calling `lpop`. Using the `top` command, I can see that redis is using 64% of CPU, while my application uses 101%.

I'm using redis to create a queue and worker. My worker is in an infinite loop, calling `lpop` and waiting for the next job to come in.

For this, I'm using the [machinery](https://github.com/RichardKnop/machinery) package. There is an issue for this [here](https://github.com/RichardKnop/machinery/issues/49), where the problem is said to be from `lpop`. However, since the comments are confusing, I'm at a loss as to what the difference is between `LPOP` and `BLPOP`, apart from the fact that one doesn't block and the other does.

Comment: LPOP will consume 100% in a loop because it returns immediately. BLPOP will block for as long as you ask it when run in a loop, so you can control this and not get into 100% CPU.

Comment: So the reason for the 100% CPU usage is that `LPOP` returns too fast. I thought you can only do 5 or 6 `LPOP`s in a second.

Comment: no, you can probably do 150k per second easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Using timed BLPOP instead of LPOP to avoid massive cpu
>   usage](https://github.com/RichardKnop/machinery/commit/54315dd9fe56a13b8aba2d2a8868fc48dfbb5795)
>
> committed 7 days ago
>
> commit 54315dd9fe56a13b8aba2d2a8868fc48dfbb5795
>
> ```
> machinery/v1/brokers/redis.go
>
> - itemBytes, err := conn.Do("LPOP", redisBroker.config.DefaultQueue)
> + itemBytes, err := conn.Do("BLPOP", redisBroker.config.DefaultQueue, "1")
> ```

Use the latest version of `machinery/v1/brokers/redis.go` 
which changes `LPOP` to `BLPOP`.

Reference: [Redis commands: BLPOP](http://redis.io/commands/BLPOP)